# Line-chart of time-series data with monthly labels on x-axis but daily data on y-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have the following data:

```
library(dplyr)
    set.seed(122)
    df <- as_tibble(rlnorm(1260, meanlog = 0.06, sdlog = 0.20))
date <- rep(c("Jan", "Feb", "Mär", "Apr", "Mai", "Jun", 
      "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dez"), 5)
```

These are supposed to be 1260 daily prices with one year = 252 days and 1 month = 21 days.

Now, I want to draw a line-chart with the daily prices on the y-axis and months on the x-axis. The code below is adapted form this thread [Graphing time-series data when date column doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56329435/graphing-time-series-data-when-date-column-doesnt-exist/56329942?noredirect=1#comment99269066_56329942):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
    as.data.frame() %>%
    rename(price = 1) %>% 
    mutate(rnames = rownames(.)) %>% 
    ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(rnames), y = price, 
                group = rep(1:5, times=1, each=252))) +
      geom_line() +
      labs(title = "Stock Price Chart", y = "Price", x = "date") +
      scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 1260, by = 21), labels = date)
```

However, I slightly changed my `df` by inserting a new first row with value `1`.

```
df <- rbind(df[0,],c(1),df[1:nrow(df),])
```

This is supposed to be the starting price at t=0. Unfortunately, the code doesn't work out now. Is there a quick fix for this?

Comment: I did this:`df <- rbind(df[0,],c(1),df[1:nrow(df),])`

Comment: we don't have `df[0,]`. This is what I get if I run your code: ```Error in df[0, ] : incorrect number of dimensions```

Comment: sorry `df  <- as_tibble(df)` is applied beforehand.

Comment: Look at my edits. You need to show all of these and make sure they are formatted correctly. Your question should be reproducible, minimal and legible (nicely formatted). Moreover, you should provide most of the information in the body of question, not the comments. That's why I added them. Read this thread about a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example ... I will post an answer shortly.

Comment: Thank you  for the help. I am going to post better examples in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  rename(price = 1) %>% 
  mutate(rnames = rownames(.)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(rnames)-1, y = price, 
             group = c(1,rep(1:5, times=1, each=252)))) +
  geom_line() +
  labs(title = "Stock Price Chart", y = "Price", x = "date") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 1260, by = 21), labels = date)
```

You can also add a new breakpoint for point `0`. by changing like `scale_x` like this:

```
scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0, seq(1, 1260, by = 21)), labels = c("t=0", date))
```

If you still want the datapoint with `price == 1` (your new row) be labeled as `Jan` then you don't need to subtract `1` from your `x` in the aesthetics and your breaks don't need to be manipulated. It works either way.

The *most important* thing to get my previous code to work with your new dataframe is changing the `group` in the aesthetics to be the same size as your new dataframe.

Comment: I just removed the paddings to the left and right with `scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1, 1260, by = 21), labels = date,expand = c(0,0))`. However, now I see that the first y-value "1" starts outside the x-axis. I would like it to lie on the first x-value "Jan". Is this possible somehow? To further clarify: the first y-value should correspond to January 1st, while the last y-value should correspond to December 31st (December 21st in my expample, as months only have 21 days)

Comment: @JjBlevins As I outlined in my answer, just need to get rid `-1` in the `aes` of `ggplot` so that line would be ```ggplot(aes(x = as.numeric(rnames), y = price,``` ... and the rest stays as what I have at the top of my answer (full solution) and you just add your `,expand = c(0,0)` in the `scale_x` function.

Comment: I said it in the answer: *If you still want the datapoint with price == 1 (your new row) be labeled as Jan then you don't need to subtract 1 from your x in the aesthetics and your breaks don't need to be manipulated.* To be clear, now you have (1261 datapoints) equal to (5 years * 12 month * 21 days + 1 day).

Comment: thank you it worked! I asked in the following thread how to add an aditional x-axis for years: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56339970/ggplot2-add-secondary-x-label-year-below-months Maybe you could help out there?

Comment: I just looked closely and even without facet grids there are these "jumps" between years. Any idea why?

Comment: @JjBlevins That's because of grouping. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731718/how-to-connect-points-of-different-groups-by-a-line-using-ggplot

Comment: is it preventable?

Comment: @JjBlevins just do not use `group` in your `aes` at all; meaning, get rid of ```group = c(1,rep(1:5, times=1, each=252))```

Comment: that solved the problem, thanks. But why use it in the first place?

Comment: @JjBlevins I personally don't think connecting different years is a good idea unless you want to see the trends in a decade (and not annually).

Comment: I understand! Thank you.